# Android oldFile.renameTo(newFile) not working on lower Android

Tags: java, android, file, android-external-storage

Hello fellow developers. I've been reading on here a lot, but can't find any solution for my problem.

I have an image file from a Camera Intent which I need to rename.
IMPORTANT: It works on Android 8.1 but doesn't work on 5.1.1 as tested.

I have no idea why, but came closer to the troublemaker. It's the `renameTo()`, which doesn't do anything, or at least I don't know of anything it does.
Here is the part of the code:

```
imgFinalName = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            format + ";" + lkwNr + ";" + telefonNr + ".jpg");
    if (imageFile.exists()){
        Log.d("Mati","Old File exists");
    }else{
        Log.d("Mati","Old File doesn't exist");
    }
    imageFile.renameTo(imgFinalName);
    Log.d("Mati","New Filename: " + imgFinalName.getName());
    Log.d("Mati","Path: " + imgFinalName.getAbsolutePath());
    if (imageFile.exists()){
        Log.d("Mati","Old File exists");
    }else{
        Log.d("Mati","Old File doesn't exist");
    }
    if (imgFinalName.exists()){
        Log.d("Mati","New File exists");
    }else{
        Log.d("Mati","New File doesn't exist");
    }
```

The Log results are as followed:

Old file exists

New Filename: `2017-12-04_21:39:03;235;123123.jpg`

Path: `/storage/sdcard/Pictures/2017-12-04_21:39:03;235;123123.jpg`

Old File exists

New File doesn't exist

So as you can see, the Old File exists, then I invoke the renameTo method, the old file still exists and the new file doesn't.

As I said, it works on Android 8.1, but doesn't on 5.1.1 and I really have no idea why... Would be nice if you guys had a solution. Feel free to ask questions

Comment: `else{
        Log.d("Mati","Old File doesn't exist");
    }`. Dont continue if so. That should be; `else{
        Log.d("Mati","Old File doesn't exist"); return;
    }`

Comment: `imageFile.renameTo(imgFinalName);`. Check the return value! `if ( !imageFile.renameTo(imgFinalName)){Toast(......); return;}`.

Comment: You did not log/tell the value of `imageFile.getAbsolutePath())`.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't matter, those are just debugging if's

Comment: `/tell the value of imageFile.getAbsolutePath()` TELL THE VALUE!!!!

Comment: And of course you should check the return value of renameTo(). OF COURSE!

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/test.jpg <- that's the value. But I solved it, the SimpleDateFormat was fault. Thanks for trying to help man :)

Comment: @greenapps I am still making some flow mistakes like forgetting to put returns etc. Thanks for reminding me, will try to do it better in the future!

Comment: `/storage/sdcard/Pictures/2017-12-04_21:39:03;235;123123.jpg` This path contains  `:` chars which are not allowed. If you had checked the return value of renameTo you would have know. And there was no SimpleDateFormat in your code so you act strange by only saying that it was fault.

Comment: I checked the return value of renameTo as you can see in my Logs. I didn't mention the SimpleDateFormat because i believed that the mistake lies in the renameTo and the storage management, since it works on Android 8.1. Thanks for the Answer man and have a good night!

Comment: `I checked the return value of renameTo as you can see in my Logs`. No you did not. I told you how to do it. That's true.

Comment: Whatever man, knowing that : is forbidden helps me, thanks

Comment: Those are not return values of renameTo(). Have a sleep. I hope tomorrow you will realise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I turned off Android Studio and wanted to go to sleep, I thought about the SimpleDateFormat.

As you can see in the filename, its:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
String format = s.format(new Date());
```

I changed it now to:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
String format = s.format(new Date());
```

And it works. Note that the "-", "_" and ":" work in android 8.1.
Those options were added in the future I guess. Anyway, what a stupid mistake, but glad I found it. Sorry for bothering.